# Trying to make a JFrame which holds two JPanels that have their own classes then using mouseListener to draw shapes on the two JPanels

Tags: java, swing

All my code works up until the point of when the shape actually needs to be drawn. I'm getting a `NullPointerExeception` when `shapeDrawer()` is called in the `mouseReleased()` method. I have tried many things and can't seem to figure it out. The idea is to make a `JFrame` in my main class then make an object of the two panels and add them to the frame then use the `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` to be able to draw a shape without the shapes overlapping on both panels. One panel draws a rectangle that only appears on one panel and then other panel draws an oval that only appears on one panel. Both `JPanel` classes are carbon copies of each other, other than one draws an oval and one draws a rectangle. Any help would be amazing I've been stuck on this for multiple hours!

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DemoJPanel1.shapeDrawer(DemoJPanel1.java:18)
    at DemoJPanel1.mouseReleased(DemoJPanel1.java:50)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks!
Brett Shepley

JPanel Class 1

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DemoJPanel1 extends JPanel implements MouseListener,ItemListener,ActionListener,MouseMotionListener {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    int startX, startY,endX,endY;
    /*--------Default Constructor to Set Up JPanel--------*/
    DemoJPanel1(){
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        mainPanel.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    /*--------Shape Painter Function--------*/
    public void shapeDrawer() {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();     
        g2.setColor(Color.white);                       
        int width = Math.abs(endX-startX);              
        int height = Math.abs(endY-startY);             
        minAndMax();
        g2.fillRect(startX, startY, width, height);
    }

    public void minAndMax() {

        if(startX > endX) {
            int temp = startX;
            startX = endX;
            endX = temp;
        }
        if(startY >endY) {
            int temp = startY;
            startY = endY;
            endY = temp;
        }
    }

    /*--------Mouse Motion Functions--------*/
        @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Test 1");
            this.startX = e.getX();         
            this.startY = e.getY();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        this.endX = e.getX();
        this.endY = e.getY();
        shapeDrawer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the first lines of the exception, and which line is throwing you this exception ? That `NullPointerException` could come from multiple places in your code.

Comment: Just added the lines of the exception!

Comment: Now we need to know what are the 18th and 50th line of this file (18 and 50 being at the beginning of the exception stacktrace). At least it would help quite a bit !

Comment: Just a small hint for your next questions: Try to make it easier for the people who answer by not posting your *entire* code here but just the relevant parts. E.g. we don't need the Not used Mouse Functions... ;)

Comment: Line 18: g2.setColor(Color.white); in shapeDrawer Line 50: shapeDrawer(); in mouseReleased

Comment: Don't use getGraphics, that is not the way to do it. Override paintComponent and use the graphics provided.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nonetheless I managed to turn it into one and then I realized that the `mainPanel` member of class `DemoJPanel1` should be removed. After I removed it, your code worked fine.

I also removed all the "listeners" apart from `MouseListener` since those other listeners are not used at all.

Here is your code with my modifications. Note that I also added a `main()` method so as to make the below code a MRE.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DemoJPanel1 extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    int startX, startY, endX, endY;

    /*--------Default Constructor to Set Up JPanel--------*/
    DemoJPanel1() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    /*--------Shape Painter Function--------*/
    public void shapeDrawer() {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        int width = Math.abs(endX - startX);
        int height = Math.abs(endY - startY);
        minAndMax();
        g2.fillRect(startX, startY, width, height);
    }

    public void minAndMax() {
        if (startX > endX) {
            int temp = startX;
            startX = endX;
            endX = temp;
        }
        if (startY > endY) {
            int temp = startY;
            startY = endY;
            endY = temp;
        }
    }

    /*--------Mouse Motion Functions--------*/
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Test 1");
        this.startX = e.getX();
        this.startY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        this.endX = e.getX();
        this.endY = e.getY();
        shapeDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                DemoJPanel1 panel = new DemoJPanel1();
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setSize(300, 400);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the drawing in paintComponent. One way you can accomplish this is to modify your class DrawPanel1 as follows.

```
public class DemoJPanel1 extends JPanel implements MouseListener,ItemListener,ActionListener,MouseMotionListener {
    //keep most of what you have but add field.
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
    /*--------Shape Painter Function--------*/
    public void shapeDrawer() {
        int width = Math.abs(endX - startX);
        int height = Math.abs(endY - startY);
        minAndMax();
        rectangle.setBounds(startX, startY, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((Graphics2D)g).fill(rectangle);
    }
}
```

So the only changes you need to make to your class. Stop using 'getGraphics' in the shaper function, that is not a good method, instead create a shape you will draw. Override paintComponent and fill the shape.

An alternative way to do this would be to use a BufferedImage and draw to that, which you *can* use getGraphics on.